# v-model on input type files vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

How to take data from v-model array in input type="file" multiple ?

```
<input type="file" multiple v-model="modFiles[index]">
<input type="file" multiple v-model="modFiles[index]">
<input type="file" multiple v-model="modFiles[index]">
```

I'm using v-for loop and I can get the first data from each modFiles[].

```
this.modFiles[0] //take the first from multiple file
```

But it's only the first data.
How can I take all the data inside modFiles[0],modFiles[1],modFiles[3] ?
And how to count the data inside each modFiles ?

```
this.modFiles[0].length //i get error here
```

thanks so much

Answer (score 5):

Bidirectional binding is not supported for `<input type="file">`, since you're not allowed to set value on such inputs (value is only set after user chooses a file).

Use `@change` event instead:

```
<input type="file" multiple @change="handleFileChange($event, index)">

methods: {
  handleFileChange(evt, index) {
    // evt.target.files contains Array-like FileList object
  }
}
```

**Update:**

In order to show/hide your submit button based on count of selected files, introduce new data property:

```
data: {
  filesSelected: 0
},
methods: {
  handleFileChange(evt, index) {
    this.filesSelected = evt.target.files.length;
  }
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<input type="submit" v-show="filesSelected > 0" />
```

Comment: what can i do if i want to make submit button doesn't appear before the user select some file? and the submit button appear after file has been selected